# How do I install Hardie Siding (Fiber Cement Siding) to Cement Backer Board?

Tags: siding, cement-board

I'm building a BBQ Island that will be framed in steel studs with cement backer board. My wife is interested in having me install Hardie Siding (technically [Hardie Square Channel Sidin](https://www.jameshardie.com/products/hardie-architectural-collection?loc=refresh)g) to finish the sides but I'm unsure how to best install fiber cement siding to cement backer board (I've only ever installed on wood substrate).

What is the best way to affix the siding? Can I just use the same fasteners used for wood substrates?
Is there a better type of substrate other than cement backer board (needs to be non-flammable)?

Appreciate any and all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, **r**ead **t**he **f**ussy **m**anual.

#### Applying James Hardie® Siding over Continuous Insulation and Non-Nailable Substrates

> Method 1: Applying Hardie® Siding Directly through C.I. and Non-Nailable Substrates 1 inches thick and less:
>
> Step 6: Ensure the Fasteners selected are available in the necessary length
>
> ii. For metal studs (with screws):
>
> The length of the minimum #8 screw shall be increased as necessary to ensure it will penetrate through the minimum
> 20 gauge metal studs by 3 full threads when applying James Hardie siding directly over max 1 inch thick non-nailable
> substrates; screw head diameter shall be as required from Step 5.

https://www.jameshardie.com/JamesHardieMainSite/media/Site-Documents/TechnicalBulletins/19-jh-over-advanced-framing-or-continuous-insulation.pdf